# How to return a specific text if a cell contains specififc text using XLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, match, xlookup

How to return corresponding texts from column E to column B. I know it is possible by the following lookup formula:

[image]

But since Excel has XLOOKUP right now and it being capable of whatever lookup can do, please explain how the same can be done with XLOOKUP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`LOOKUP` Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) has the following syntax:

> LOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_vector, [result_vector])

The [`XLOOKUP` Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) has the following syntax:

> XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])

As such, you should be able to see that the first 3 parameters of `XLOOKUP` correspond to the three parameters of `LOOKUP`, with the primary difference that `result_vector`/`return_array` is no longer optional.  If it was omitted from your `LOOKUP`, then you would need to replace it with either a copy of `lookup_vector`/`lookup_array` (if one of the dimensions of your array was 1), or with the last row/column of `lookup_vector`/`lookup_array`.

(For arrays where neither dimension was 1, this gives more control — `LOOKUP` would swap between Horizontal or Vertical lookups depending on whether the array was wider than it was tall or not.  This is part of why `HLOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP` were preferred, especially for dynamically sized arrays)

As such, you might think that you should be able to just change `=LOOKUP(..)` to `=XLOOKUP(..)` and be done with it… except you would be wrong.

The issue is in those 3 new optional arguments — specifically, in the second one, `match_mode`.  This has 4 possible values:

> **match_mode** (Optional) Specify the match type:
> ​ 0 - Exact match. If none found, return #N/A. This is the default.
> -1 - Exact match. If none found, return the next smaller item.
> ​ 1 - Exact match. If none found, return the next larger item.
> ​ 2 - A wildcard match where *, ?, and ~ have [special meaning](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-wildcard-characters-in-searches-ef94362e-9999-4350-ad74-4d2371110adb).

You see, `LOOKUP` functioned as "if none found, return the next smaller item", while `XLOOKUP` defaults instead to "if none found, return #N/A".

This means that, in order to make `XLOOKUP` behave like `LOOKUP` used to, you need to specify a `match_mode` of `-1`.  Like so:

```
=XLOOKUP(1.1,1/COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$D$1:$D$3&"*"),$E$1:$E$3,,-1)
```

(You may also notice that I have left `if_not_found` unspecified, so that it stays as the default value — this is done by putting the 2 commas with nothing between them)